# Differences between strafe jumping in Quake series?

Tags: quake-3, quake-2, quake

In Quake 1-3, what is the difference between strafe jumping between them? Do they keep the same vector summation overshoot from Quake 1, or does each engine/game vary?

Comment: They are different :)

Comment: I suppose (actually read about, but lost link) strafe jumping was consequently reduced from 1 to 2 to 3 part. AFAIR John Carmack was against all nerdy-bug-feature-hidden things.

Answer (score -1):

I would say that strafe jumping is different from the different Quake games for the fact that the three games run on different game engines. So, it would vary from which game engine was used to make and run the game.